# HTML5 canvas color reduction

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to find a way or algorithm to convert a HTML5 canvas element into a 16color bmp, the same format MS Paint do. I wasn't unable to find or figure out a way to do, I found some another languages algorithms but seems to difficult for me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can actually save it in that format. You may have to simulate a 16 color image instead, then use Mohsen's answer to save it in BMP format. Try looking at the [Pixastic javascript library](http://www.pixastic.com/).

Comment: Ignore the link; it doesn't say anything about 16-bit or indexed colors.